# How to authenticate Proxy with Requests Python module?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Here is the segment of code that is causing an issue:

```py
proxies = {"http": "http://%s:%s@proxy_address:8080" %(user, pwd),
"https": "http://%s:%s@proxy_address:8080" %(user, pwd)}

requests.get('https://www.apple.com/', proxies=proxies)
```

I receive the error: '''ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))'''

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I sure that my username and password is correct.

Thanks.